# LINQ conditional query where value might be null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to write a query to select data from database. I have the following code :

```
 from notes in ctx.Notes
 .Where(x => x.UserId== user.UserId 
 || x.UserId == user.FamilyId 
 || x.UserId == user.CompanyId).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The problem with this is that the FamilyId and CompanyId are both nullable types and may not have any value at all which corrupts the whole query. How can I rewrite it so it only looks for FamilyId/CompanyId if they have values?

Comment: Do you want a Linq or SQL answer?

Comment: I'd prefer linq thanks !

Comment: Don't know if LINQ-to-SQL can work with it: `|| (user.FamilyId.HasValue && x.UserId == user.FamilyId)`

Comment: @Oliver: If you use `!= null` instead of `HasValue`, Linq-To-SQL can definitely handle it. I doubt if it works for `HasValue`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Oliver this will generate compleq SQL-query, that is hard to optimize on SqlServer. So, I advice do not use this method

Comment: That's my doubt too. So just a comment and not an answer. Currently it would take to much time for me to set up a corresponding database and test all these cases.

Comment: @Oliver this is exactly the approach that i am looking for however both .HasValue and != null don't seem to be working unfortunately, i dont get any response to query from the database at all.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem with `FamilyId` being null? Surely if it is null then the `UserId==FamilyId` would be false which would have the same effect of not including that clause at all...

Comment: @Chris oh that seem to work just it is very slow, I limted to result just to select 10 records and it did work fine with .HasValue but it took almost 50 seconds to pull these records. I guess Backs is right

Comment: @Edward: It may be worth clarifying that in the question then. When you talked about it "corrupting" the query I assumed that you were getting incorrect results back or something. Running very slow seems to be a completely different problem to wrong results.

Comment: @Chris At first I tried to pull around 5000 records so even waiting for 2 minutes i didn't get any result, at that time i didn't know it works but it slow, only limiting it to fewer records I realised it is slow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create condition query:

```
var users = ctx.Notes.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);

if (user.FamilyId != null)
{
    users = users.Union(ctx.Notes.Where(x => x.UserId == user.FamilyId));
}

if (user.CompanyId != null)
{
    users = users.Union(ctx.Notes.Where(x => x.UserId == user.CompanyId ));
}

var result = users.ToArray();
```

Comment: This should work, but I think it creates multiple select statements under the hood, which could maybe hit performance. So check the SQL execution plan if it is okay for your purpose.

Comment: @Oliver no, it does not generate multiple select statements. It genereates one select with unions

Comment: @Backs I guess you are right, the .HasValue/!=null is very slow, it did work but pulling 10 records took around a minute..

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just add an AND clause to check if it's not null:

```
 from notes in ctx.Notes.Where(x => x.UserId== user.UserId || (user.FamilyId ! =null && x.UserId == user.FamilyId) || (user.CompanyId !=null && x.UserId == user.CompanyId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: As i wrote above, this will generate horrible sql-query that will difficult to optimize bby SqlServer